# Converting a large hexadecimal string to decimal

Tags: powershell

The following hexadecimal value:

```
0x82e83f52d81253e79c4
```

is the following in base 10:

```
38636990646568762636740
```

If I try to convert it to a `decimal`:

```
[decimal] '0x82e83f52d81253e79c4'
```

I get the following:

```
Cannot convert value "0x82e83f52d81253e79c4" to type "System.Decimal". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

What's a good way to convert that large hexadecimal value in a string to a `decimal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`[bigint]::Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) to parse the hexadecimal string as a `BigInteger`, then cast to `[decimal]`:

```
# define hex string
$string = '0x82e83f52d81253e79c4'

# remove 0x prefix
$string = $string -replace '^0x'

# prepend `0` to avoid having [bigint]::Parse interpret number as signed
$string = "0${string}"

# now parse it as a [bigint]
$bigint = [bigint]::Parse($string, [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowHexSpecifier)

# finally cast to `[decimal]`
[decimal]$bigint
```

This can easily be turned into a small utility function:

```
function ConvertFrom-Hexadecimal
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$Hexadecimal
  )

  $string = '0{0}' -f ($Hexadecimal -replace '^0x')

  return [decimal][bigint]::Parse($string, [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowHexSpecifier)
}
```

```
PS ~> $decimal = ConvertFrom-Hexadecimal '0x82e83f52d81253e79c4'
PS ~> $decimal -is [decimal]
True
PS ~> $decimal
38636990646568762636740
```

Comment: In your function definition, it looks like the second parameter name is missing? `[ValidateSet()] [type]`

Comment: @dharmatech I copy-pasted the wrong thing into the answer, updated now :-)